# How to represent "backspace" key in autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

My keyboard is buggy right now and keys are double typing when they're not meant to. I found this [autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script [online](https://gist.github.com/QuietNoise/8339ec2cc8607978a8df3c290e2f453c) that ignores keystrokes if they're registered again in a very short timespan. The code works by listing all the broken keys contiguously in a string but I'm not sure how to list my backspace key. The [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm) states the backspace is key is just `backspace` but it's not working for me. This is what I have so far.

```
;List all your broken keys between quotes below. I.e. if your broken keys are g and f then the line below shoud be 
;brokenKeys := "gf"
brokenKeys := "fosbaituwrvlk"

;timepan in which subsequent keystrokes should be ignored.
fixOffset := 80

;These are typical values for a starter AHK script
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

;This array will hold timers for each broken key
lastTimePressed := {}

;Create timer with current time for each broken key
Loop, Parse, brokenKeys
{
    lastTimePressed[A_LoopField] := A_TickCount
}

;lastTimePressed := A_TickCount

;Assign a hotkey handler for each broken key
Loop, Parse, brokenKeys
{    
    keyName := 
    Hotkey, $%A_LoopField%, HotKeyHandler 
}

HotKeyHandler:    
    pressedKey := SubStr(pressedKey,2)SubStr(A_ThisHotKey,2)    
    sinceLastPress := A_TickCount - lastTimePressed[pressedKey]
    if (sinceLastPress > fixOffset) { ;send the hijacked key only when sufficient time has passed
        lastTimePressed[pressedKey] := A_TickCount
        Send %pressedKey%
    }
return
```

**EDIT**: I've updated my code. Currently after I click `backspace`, the backspace key registers but after that all the `brokenKeys` no longer respond. From debugging, the `pressedKey` variable seems to have been affected by clicking `backspace` and so `lastTimePressed[pressedKey]` is not working in the `hotKeyHandler` function.

```
;List all your broken keys
brokenKeys := "f|o|s|b|a|i|t|u|w|r|v|l|k|'|backspace"

;timepan in which subsequent keystrokes should be ignored.
fixOffset := 80

;These are typical values for a starter AHK script
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

;This array will hold timers for each broken key
lastTimePressed := {}

;Create timer with current time for each broken key
Loop, Parse, brokenKeys, |
{
    lastTimePressed[A_LoopField] := A_TickCount
}

;lastTimePressed := A_TickCount

;Assign a hotkey handler for each broken key
Loop, Parse, brokenKeys, |
{    
    keyName := 
    Hotkey, $%A_LoopField%, HotKeyHandler 
}

HotKeyHandler:
    pressedKey := SubStr(pressedKey,2)SubStr(A_ThisHotKey,2)
    sinceLastPress := A_TickCount - lastTimePressed[pressedKey]
    if (sinceLastPress > fixOffset) { ;send the hijacked key only when sufficient time has passed
        lastTimePressed[pressedKey] := A_TickCount
        if (pressedKey == "backspace"){
            Send {backspace}
        } else {
            Send %pressedKey%
        }
    }
return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to get a solution from [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=104622)

```
;List all your broken keys
brokenKeys := "f|o|s|b|a|i|t|u|w|r|v|l|k|Backspace"

;timepan in which subsequent keystrokes should be ignored.
fixOffset := 80

;These are typical values for a starter AHK script
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

;This array will hold timers for each broken key
lastTimePressed := {}

;Create timer with current time for each broken key
Loop, Parse, brokenKeys, |
    lastTimePressed[A_LoopField] := A_TickCount

;lastTimePressed := A_TickCount

;Assign a hotkey handler for each broken key
Loop, Parse, brokenKeys, |
{    
    keyName := 
    Hotkey, $%A_LoopField%, HotKeyHandler 
}
Return
HotKeyHandler:    
    pressedKey := SubStr(A_ThisHotKey,2) ;<<<< corrected  
    sinceLastPress := A_TickCount - lastTimePressed[pressedKey]
    if (sinceLastPress > fixOffset) { ;send the hijacked key only when sufficient time has passed
        lastTimePressed[pressedKey] := A_TickCount
        Send {%pressedKey%} ;<<<< corrected
    }
return
```

Comment: Nice one. thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the parsing loop can accept a delimiter to parse on, otherwise it will just parse individual characters in a string.

```
;List all your broken keys between quotes below. I.e. if your broken keys are g and f then the line below should be 
;brokenKeys := "gf"
;brokenKeys := "fosbaituwrvlk"
brokenKeys := "f|o|s|b|a|i|t|u|w|r|v|l|k|backspace"

;timepan in which subsequent keystrokes should be ignored.
fixOffset := 80 ; MILLISECONDS

;These are typical values for a starter AHK script
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

;This array will hold timers for each broken key
lastTimePressed := {}

;Create timer with current time and hotkey for each broken key
Loop, Parse, brokenKeys, |
{
    lastTimePressed[A_LoopField] := A_TickCount
    Hotkey, ~$%A_LoopField%, HotKeyHandler
}
 ; YOUR VERSION IS PARSING INDIVIDUAL CHARACTERS
 ; THIS ONE IS USING "|" TO SEPARATE THE KEY NAMES
 ; NOW YOU CAN USE A KEY NAME COMPOSED OF MORE THAN ONE CHARACTER
 ; JUST SEPARATE EACH ONE WITH A "|" IN THE 'BROKENKEYS' VARIABLE ABOVE.
 ; I ALSO INCLUDED BOTH LOOP ACTIONS IN ONE LOOP, INSTEAD OF TWO.
 ; WHICH SAVES TIME IN LOADING, ALBEIT MARGINALLY.
Return
 
 HotKeyHandler:    
    pressedKey := SubStr(pressedKey,2)SubStr(A_ThisHotKey,2)    
    sinceLastPress := A_TickCount - lastTimePressed[pressedKey]
    if (sinceLastPress > fixOffset) { ;send the hijacked key only when sufficient time has passed
        lastTimePressed[pressedKey] := A_TickCount
        Send %pressedKey%
    }
return
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. When I try to run this script, it just makes the `brokenKeys` not work at all. On the brightside, it is picking up on the `backspace` key. I've tried removing the `Return` on line 24 under your comment and splitting the single loop into the origina; two loops but neither is working. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Oh will you look at that, I forgot the “$” modifier on the hot key in your original script. I edited it now, and included the pass through modifier as well for good luck. Try it again, if that doesn’t work, I have no idea

Comment: I just realized the pass through option might be counter intuitive to what you are trying to do. If it starts allowing double presses, remove the tilde.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not working. I tried removing `backspace` from `brokenKeys` but your script was allowing double typing (even with `~` removed). So then I went back to my original script (with double loops) and added `|` to `brokenKeys` and both loops (but did not add `Backspace`) and the script is working fine as before. However when I add `Backspace` the script works fine until I hit backspace at which point the literal words backspace appear and the `brokenKeys` all stop responding.

Comment: I figured the appearance of the words `backspace` was because I was sending back the string backspace instead of the actual backspace key. That was an easy fix: `if (pressedKey == "backspace"){Send {backspace}}` but I can't figure out how to fix the issue where the `brokenKeys` stop responding after backspace is pressed.

Comment: I've updated my question to include the new code. It seems the issue lies in `pressedKey`.

Comment: Try using a msgbox to view the pressedKey var after it gets assigned by the substr assignment in hotkeyHandler, from what I understand the double subStr doesn’t make sense, but I am not very familiar with the Hotkey command, as I usually hard code my hotkeys

Comment: Yep so I'm printing `pressedKey`. Before I click `backspace`  msgbox is showing me the correct key I just pressed. When I click `backspace` the characters "backspace" correctly show. But after that, when I click "p" instead of showing "p", messagebox shows "ackspacep". Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245119/discussion-between-t-lube-and-mistakamikaze).